# Localize strings in app with multiple values for one language

Tags: wpf, string, localization

I want to localize strings in my WPF application.
Therefor I found this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies, which helps me to understand what the main thing with localization in WPF is about.

My application doesn't need to have translated strings in several languages but different values for different brandings. I am compiling the application for different customers with different behavior (images, texts, etc).

I think the way the tutorial from above doesn't solve my problem because

```
CurrentUICulture
```

is used and I don't want to control it with different languages.

Is there a better way to use the it for my needs?

**Another way** I thought of, is to create static classes which holds all the strings. Since I'm already using compilation symbols it would be very easy to implement. But if WPF already provides a better way to handle this situation, I don't need to implement it on myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using WPF, you could define the relevant strings and images as resources, and use a separate `ResourceDictionary` (Xaml resource file) for each customer.

In your application's resources, you can import the default resources first, then your customer-specific overrides.  It'll be last in, first out, so any resource that exists in your customer's file will take precedence over the one in the defaults file. Likewise, a if a resource *isn't* defined in the customer's resources, you'll use the one in the defaults.

```xml
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="Defaults.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomerA.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

You may want to do this programmatically in C# and use something like `#if CUSTOMER_A` to pick which resources are brought in.

The individual Xaml files are straightforward:

**Defaults.xaml:**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <s:String x:Key="MainWindowTitle">Snazzy Application</s:String>
  <BitmapImage x:Key="MainLogo" UriSource="Images/DefaultLogo.png" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**CustomerA.xaml:**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <s:String x:Key="MainWindowTitle">Customer A's Amazeballs Application</s:String>
  <BitmapImage x:Key="MainLogo" UriSource="Images/CustomerALogo.png" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Use the resources the same way you'd use any Xaml resource:

```xml
<Window Title="{StaticResource MainWindowTitle}" />
<Image Source="{StaticResource MainLogo}" />
```

Comment: This helps me alot. Thank you!